# How can I print all filter matrixes from specific layers in pre-trained model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, feature-extraction, tf.keras

I use VGG19 pre-trained model as feature extractor from specific layers. As I written below, I want to get features from the layer that 'block5_conv4' which is the last 5th layer.

```
model = keras.applications.VGG19(
include_top=True,
weights="imagenet",
input_tensor=None,
input_shape=None,
pooling=None,
)

model = Model(model.input, model.layers[-5].output)
img_data = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)
img_data = preprocess_input(img_data)

vgg_feature = model.predict(img_data)
```

At that stage vgg_feature.shape is (1,7,7,512). What I understand from this is that I have 512 7x7 filters and if it is correct I want to print all these 7x7 matrices.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

vgg_feature[:,:,:,0] and vgg_feature[:,:,:,511] gives all filters as 7x7 matrices.